# In C++ leave scope when error occurs without exceptions

Tags: c++, exception

In bash we can say:

```
(
set -e
function OnError {  caller | { read line file; echo "in $file:$line" >&2; };  }
trap OnError ERR  ## catch exception
echo hello  ## step 1
false
echo "never come here" 
)
# continue here
```

Every command returns exit code. Flag `-e` tells bash to check every result and exit if it is non-zero.
Exceptions in C++ provides similar logic:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void step1(){
    cout<<"hello"<<endl;
}
void step2(){
    throw std::runtime_error("step2 always fail");
}
void step3(){
    cout<<"never come here"<<endl;
}

int main(){
   try{
      step1();
      step2();  // throws
      step3();  // never come here
   }catch(...){
      cerr<<"caught error"<<endl;
   }
   // continue here
}
```

And this works pretty same. But need additional manipulations to detect from where exception was thrown.

Often C++ developers refuse using exceptions with `-fno-exceptions`. And code become looking like C – need to check result for every action.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int step1(){
    cout<<"hello"<<endl;
    return 0;
}
int step2(){
    return -1;
}
int step3(){
    cout<<"never come here"<<endl;
    return 0;
}

#define CHECK(err,msg) \
    if(err){ \
       cerr<<"error in "<<msg<<endl; \
       break; \
    }

int main(){
    while(0){
      CHECK(step1(),"step1");
      CHECK(step2(),"step2");
      CHECK(step3(),"step3");
    }
    // continue here;
}
```

And that looks slightly cumbersome. But here we can directly track file:line.

I would like to have **clean code without exceptions**. Like:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

enum Result {SUCCESS,FAIL};

Result step1(){
    cout<<"hello"<<endl;
    return SUCCESS;
}
Result step2(){
    return FAIL;
}
Result step3(){
    cout<<"never come here"<<endl;
    return SUCCESS;
}

int main(){
   {
    step1();  // success
    step2();  // fail , interrupt execution and go out of scope
    step3();  // never come here
   }
   // continue here
}
```

How to achieve same behavior as in bash keeping code simple and and clean without exceptions?

Comment: What's wrong with exceptions for you? It exactly does what you want, no matter if you `try` `catch` or not.

Comment: Qt does not use exceptions. They have reasons. People also does not use exceptions in embedded systems. It's a holywar. Anyway imagine -fno-exceptions is a convention in some team/environment/project.

Comment: There is a boost outcome library, and set of macros that enable you exiting the scope if the call fails, but that requires you to rewrite your application.  https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_71_0/libs/outcome/doc/html/tutorial/essential/result.html

Answer (score 0):

You can (ab)use the fact that C++ uses lazy evaluation for checking boolean logic:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

bool step1(){
    cout<<"hello"<<endl;
    return true;
}
bool step2(){
    return false;
}
bool step3(){
    cout<<"never come here"<<endl;
    return true;
}

bool executeSteps() {
    return step1() && step2() && step3();
}

int main(){
    executeSteps();
}
```

Since `step2()` returns `false`, the whole condition cannot evaluate to `true`, so the rest of it isn't even checked.

You don't even need a separate function for that (although ignoring the result of boolean calculations might be confusing to the readers):

```
int main(){
    step1() && step2() && step3();
}
```

Comment: @kyb It sounds like you really want to use exceptions. Exceptions can tell you [`what()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/exception/what) went wrong (and you can debug them easily when it comes to that). Even better, you can throw multiple types of exceptions and have type tell you what went wrong instead of a string.

Comment: Of course, you could do above with enum (where there is only one success state equal to `0`) and use `||` instead, but that makes the set of outcomes limited to the sope of the enum.

Answer (score 0):

There are several implementations for such approach:

From https://buckaroo.pm/posts/error-handling-in-cpp:

> - [loopperfect/neither](https://github.com/loopperfect/neither)
> - [std::expected](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4109.pdf)
> - [Boost Outcome](https://github.com/ned14/outcome)
> - [beark/ftl](https://github.com/beark/ftl)

and also https://github.com/TartanLlama/expected, imo the best.